# Add two users to parse object and Query

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to create a parse object with two users and query for the object using both users. My get other user method returns the other user i want to add to the group.

```
String id;
final ParseUser[] user = new ParseUser[1];

public void getOtherUser()
{
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("username", "amanda");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                user[0] = objects.get(0);
                addUserGroup();

            } else {
                // Something went wrong.
            }
        }
    });
}
```

my add userGroup created a parse object with both users

```
private void addUserGroup()
{
    final ParseObject group = new ParseObject("UserGroup");
    group.put("from", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    group.put("to", user[0]);
    group.saveInBackground((new SaveCallback() {
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            id = group.getObjectId();
        }
    }));

}
```

After ive done this i want to be able to be able to update the parse object with new content and query for the object based on both users. The following mehtod is breaking on me though and im not sure why.

```
 private void getData()
{
    final double[] result = {0};
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserGroup");
    query.whereEqualTo("from",ParseUser.getCurrentUser() );
    query.whereEqualTo("to", user);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> commentList, ParseException e) {
            Log.d("found", "woohoo");
        }
    });
```

Its returning the following error 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for ParseObject: class [Lcom.parse.ParseUser;

anybody know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call ParseUser.getCurrentUser() parse return a user object.  Now assuming you want to query usernames you need to change the ParseUser.getCurrentUser() to ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername()

```
private void addUserGroup()
{
    final ParseObject group = new ParseObject("UserGroup");
    group.put("from", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
    group.put("to", user[0]);
    group.saveInBackground((new SaveCallback() {
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            id = group.getObjectId();
        }
    }));

}

private void getData() 
{ 
    final double[] result = {0};
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserGroup");
    query.whereEqualTo("from",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername() );
    query.whereEqualTo("to", user);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> commentList, ParseException e) {
            Log.d("found", "woohoo");
        } 
    }); 
}
```